# Complicated mySQL Query Order By

Tags: mysql

Example Data:

```
╔════╦════════════╦════════════╦═══════╦═══════════╦════════╗
║ ID ║   START    ║    STOP    ║ USER  ║   FILE    ║  SIZE  ║
╠════╬════════════╬════════════╬═══════╬═══════════╬════════╣
║  1 ║ 1330133409 ║ 1330133410 ║ user1 ║ file1.zip ║ 300000 ║
║  2 ║ 1330133409 ║ 1330133410 ║ user1 ║ file2.zip ║ 300500 ║
║  3 ║ 1330133409 ║ 1330133410 ║ user2 ║ file1.zip ║ 300000 ║
║  4 ║ 1330133409 ║ 1330133410 ║ user2 ║ file2.zip ║ 300500 ║
║  5 ║ 1330133409 ║ 1330133410 ║ user1 ║ file3.zip ║ 500000 ║
║  6 ║ 1330133409 ║ 1330133310 ║ user6 ║ file3.zip ║ 500000 ║
╚════╩════════════╩════════════╩═══════╩═══════════╩════════╝
```

I need to create a MySQL query that computes `PER_USER_AVERAGE_BANDWIDTH` where `PER_USER_AVERAGE_BANDWIDTH = SUM(SIZE) / (STOP - START)`, and then order by `PER_USER_AVERAGE_BANDWIDTH` to produce results like this:

```
╔═══════╦════════════════════════════╗
║ USER  ║ PER_USER_AVERAGE_BANDWIDTH ║
╠═══════╬════════════════════════════╣
║ user3 ║ 110.37                     ║
║ user1 ║ 100.25                     ║
║ user2 ║ 75.70                      ║
╚═══════╩════════════════════════════╝
```

Clear as mud ;) Anyone?

Comment: +1 for the lovely layout. Have'n't seen that sort of thing since Paradox for Dos 2.0

Comment: You show data for `user1`, `user2`, and `user6` - where does `user3` in the result set come from? Also, how do you `SUM(SIZE)` (multiple rows) but only use one row in `(STOP - START)`? There are three rows for `user1` - which would you expect to be used for that part of the calculation? (Yes, I realize in this case `STOP` and `START` are the same values for all three rows, but the database doesn't know that when it's parsing the SQL.)

Comment: @TonyHopkinson: That should be my +1!  Sadface ;)  FYI http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html

Comment: @eggyal, + 1 for trying to make sure you got the credit. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think your average should be total size over total duration, grouped by user:

```
SELECT   USER,
         SUM(SIZE) / SUM(STOP - START) AS PER_USER_AVERAGE_BANDWIDTH
FROM     my_table
GROUP BY USER
ORDER BY PER_USER_AVERAGE_BANDWIDTH DESC
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/df2e0/3/0).

Comment: This is not an average. It is the overall bandwidth. Different things. Use a pencil and paper and you'll get it.

Comment: @Bohemian: it most certainly is an average.  Imagine 100 transfers, one of 1GiB over 1s and the other 99 of 1B over 1000s each; I calculate total amount transferred (1.00000009GiB) and divide by total duration (99001s) to yield the (weighted) average throughput of 84.7kbps.  Sir Rufo's answer, by contrast, yields the unweighted average of 81.9Mbps.

Comment: I interpreted the question as asking for the "normal" (ie *unweighted*) average. Your answer, which gives the *weighted* average, may also be a reasonable interpretation. Both are valid and useful statistics. I think the normal average is more useful, since one bad download experience that happened to be a bid download doesn't then mar 99 good download experiences of small files.

Comment: @Bohemian: On the contrary, the opposite is true.  In the example I gave above, there was 1 great download experience (at **8Gbps**), followed by 99 *terrible* download experiences (at **0.008bps**).  The unweighted average yields a pretty decent **81.9Mbps**, which takes less account of the much more common terrible download experiences than the weighted average of **84.7kbps**!

Answer (score 2):

straight forward for average

```
SELECT 
  `user`,
  AVG( size / ( stop - start ) ) per_user_average_bandwidth
FROM
  tab_dl
GROUP BY `user`
ORDER BY per_user_average_bandwidth DESC
```

[SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/67d0c/1/0)

Comment: @DanielAbrams if you accept you should accept - http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 0):

This query should do it:

```
SELECT USER, (SUM(SIZE) / (STOP - START)) AS PER_USER_AVERAGE_BANDWIDTH
FROM table
GROUP BY USER, stop, start
ORDER BY PER_USER_AVERAGE_BANDWIDTH DESC
```

This will give you the average bandwidth per user per unique time frame (i.e. you will get 2 rows for a user if they download file 1 and file 2 between time 1 and time 5 and file 3 between time 1 and time 10).

Comment: this did not answer the question at all - see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/df2e0/5/0 - btw `GROUP BY ID, start, stop` with **unique** `ID` is like `GROUP BY ID` ;o)

Comment: I probably was not clear. Almost there. Should be average bandwidth per user for all files downloaded by that user. So, one result per user.

Comment: @SirRufo That was left over from before the question was edited and I updated my answer originally, before the columns were clear.

Comment: @DanielAbrams that assumes that there will only be one time period per user, otherwise the calculation would be incorrect.